# Display url thumbnail generated by GEE in python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to generate a thumbnail image from GEE using python, but when I try to do so, it only returns the object and not the image. I am following the code [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api).

Here is the relevant code.

```
import ee
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from IPython.display import Image

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

# Import the MODIS land cover collection.
lc = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')

# Import the MODIS land surface temperature collection.
lst = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')

# Import the USGS ground elevation image.
elv = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')

# Initial date of interest (inclusive).
i_date = '2017-01-01'

# Final date of interest (exclusive).
f_date = '2020-01-01'

# Selection of appropriate bands and dates for LST.
lst = lst.select('LST_Day_1km', 'QC_Day').filterDate(i_date, f_date)

# Define the urban location of interest as a point near Lyon, France.
u_lon = 4.8148
u_lat = 45.7758
u_poi = ee.Geometry.Point(u_lon, u_lat)

# Define the rural location of interest as a point away from the city.
r_lon = 5.175964
r_lat = 45.574064
r_poi = ee.Geometry.Point(r_lon, r_lat)

scale = 1000  # scale in meters


# Define a region of interest with a buffer zone of 1000 km around Lyon.
roi = u_poi.buffer(1e6)

# Reduce the LST collection by mean.
lst_img = lst.mean()

# Adjust for scale factor.
lst_img = lst_img.select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(0.02)

# Convert Kelvin to Celsius.
lst_img = lst_img.select('LST_Day_1km').add(-273.15)

# Create a URL to the styled image for a region around France.
url = lst_img.getThumbUrl({
    'min': 10, 'max': 30, 'dimensions': 512, 'region': roi,
    'palette': ['blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']})
print(url)

# Display the thumbnail land surface temperature in France.
print('\nPlease wait while the thumbnail loads, it may take a moment...')
Image(url=url)
```

When I type Image(url), the only output is a an object. I have tried to use various display(), show(), etc options.

How can I display the url?

Comment: what is the output of `print(url)`?